# Shopping cart/list but no payment

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I'm currently using HTML and CSS to build a static website, I don't know Javascript or PHP, but can implement jQuery into websites ie copy and pasting into the right place.

Is there anyway I could add a shopping cart but without the payment gateway part?

The idea is customers can add to list, but when they finish shopping they are asked to call a telephone number.

The reason being so customers have a list of items they've added to the list in front of them when ordering over the phone.

When they add the item to the list it also has to add the minimum quantity.

The payment part is not required because the store owners are brokers and the price of their goods change everyday.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some hints: You need to store the order somehow if you don't want to lose it when the user navigates. You could use [cookies](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie) or [local storage](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/localstorage). I can't think on any other solution, but it might be any. The "cart" may be just a div where you show the items the user selected, either grabbing them from the local storage on page load or adding them when the user clicks the "add to cart" button. Of course, your stored data should be updated if the user adds or removes something from the cart. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could follow these steps to make a php cart, then add the contact information in the final screen with an according sign (phone number, contact info):

http://v3.thewatchmakerproject.com/journal/276/building-a-simple-php-shopping-cart

Would be too long to post the code here, but:

1) You will need to set up a database,

2) You will have to create a session and a cart in PHP,

3) You will have to add options for deleting/updating products,

4) And you will need to decorate the display with css ;)